# How to call other fragment from image view onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I want to call class FragmentDiagnosis from image view click listener. Im so confused about how to call the other class from click listener? I've tried use intent, but there was error on it. For anyone who understand about this problem, please help me. I will appreciate it, thank you so much.

```
package com.pakarayam;
import android.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_home, container, false);
    configureImageView(view);
    return view;
}
private void configureImageView(View view) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ImageView mulai = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mulai);
mulai.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent iMulai = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FragmentDiagnosis.class);
        startActivity(iMulai);
}});
}}
```

Comment: please read basic about fragment http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/fragments/creating.html and http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Instead of using `startActivity ` and new Fragment in container in same way as you are adding `FragmentHome` Fragment in Activity

Comment: `startActivity` is not a called for showing `Fragment` it is used for switching from Acivities. Use `FragmentManger` and `FragmentTransation` to show your fragment

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK this code didn't work.. what should I do now?             public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.layout.activity_fragment_diagnosis,new FragmentDiagnosis(),"FragmentDiagnosis");
            ft.commit();
        }});'

Comment: @PujaPutri: yes are u getting any issue?

Comment: Yes I do.  When i run this code I found this app unfortunately stopped. any solution? @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: @PujaPutri: plz show crash logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
public void onClick(View v)
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    YourFragment yourFragment= new YourFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.your_activity_id, yourFragment, "FRAGMENT");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: @sideshowbarker Its worked for me, but why 'home fragment' stay appear when I click the button 'diagnosis fragment'. So this class cover up the other class. Any solution again?

Comment: @PujaPutri This answer was posted by mehrdad khosravi. I just made [a minor edit to it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34719824/revisions) to get the code to display with the expected formatting.

Comment: Its worked for me, but why 'home fragment' stay appear when I click the button 'diagnosis fragment'. So this class cover up the other class. Any solution again? @mehrdadkhosravi

Answer (score 0):

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, Bundle bundle) {
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left,
                    R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_right);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame1, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MenuChangeActivity", "Add fragment error");
        }
    }
```